# Opensea nft seller problem

Tags: nft

I tried selling my nft on opensea the buyer is clean and am clean, he purchased my nft and then it asked for gas fee payment which wasn’t successful and i messed up since i was new to this and couldn’t complete the transaction, then the help center started telling me to put more money and accusing me with money laundering and stuff i apologized to the buyer since he started getting al angry and stuff and told him i rejected everything on my wallet tho i confirmed some transaction that didn’t do anything. Can this lead to any legal action i was clean not a scammer nor anything just trying to sell my nft and didn’t work well

Comment: The "help center" sounds scammy. If I were you, I would change my wallet. The transactions you made could have made your wallet vulnerable. So, nothing to worry legally for you, only economically.